# Amazon AWS - Use AMI for hosting site, do I need to update OS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have been looking at Amazon AWS services and trying to get up to speed.

I have a WordPress / WooCommerce site that I want to put online.  Normally I would either upload it to a cPanel host that I use or rent a managed server.

I have looked at the Amazon WordPress AMI by Bitnami and am wondering if this is a good alternative?

I have always shied away from using a VPS because I have to deal with updating and patching the underlying OS, am I right in thinking that if I use an Amazon AMI then all of this is taken care of?

Comment: No, updating and patching is not taken care of with an AMI. An EC2 instance is essentially the same thing as a VPS. If you want managed hosting, AWS isn't really the place.

Comment: I'm confused by their documentation which states 'Updates are provided via a pre-configured yum repository hosted in each Amazon EC2 region. Security updates are automatically applied on the initial boot of the AMI' - This made it sound like I don't need to worry about this aspect

Comment: If a car dealership said "Cars are automatically fueled before the first drive" would you think you have unlimited fuel and never need to go to a gas station?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to update OS manually.

> 'Updates are provided via a pre-configured yum repository hosted in
>   each Amazon EC2 region. Security updates are automatically applied on
>   the initial boot of the AMI'

This means that whenever there is an update available, you will notified of it upon login via Message of the Day. Below is the example of the update message on login.

```
There are 12 security update(s) out of 25 total update(s) available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
```

Comment: Please note that even if you do `sudo yum update`, not all updates will be "live." Depending on the update, you will need to restart services, or even restart the instance. Rebooting after update will do this.